# How to improve performance with an ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I have a query that is reading through approximately 2.4m rows of data.

The query itself is running well but the ORDER BY clause is causing performance issues. If I remove the ORDER BY the query takes 0.03 seconds to execute. With the ORDER BY it can take 4.5 to 5 seconds.

Is there anyway I an optimise this query further? Indexes have been added so that isn't a solution.

**EDIT 1 -** 
This query is a shortened version of a much bigger PDO query so I think the join is necessary. You can see the main query at the bottom of this post.

```
SELECT t.processing_time, t.paymentType, t.status, t.merchantTransactionId, t.paymentBrand, t.amount, t.currency, t.code, t.holder, t.bin, t.last4Digits, t.recurringType, m.name AS merchant, c.name AS channel, concat(UPPER(SUBSTRING(trim(sp.status_description),1,1)), lower(SUBSTRING(trim(sp.status_description),2))) as status_description
FROM transactionsV2 t
JOIN channels c
ON t.entityId = c.uuid
JOIN merchants m
ON m.uuid = c.sender
JOIN status_payments sp 
ON t.code = sp.status_code
JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.processing_time FROM transactionsV2 t
    JOIN channels c ON t.entityId = c.uuid
    JOIN merchants m ON m.uuid = c.sender
    WHERE (t.processing_time >= "2018-11-08 00:00:00")
    AND (t.processing_time <= "2018-11-12 23:59:59")
    ORDER BY t.processing_time DESC
    LIMIT 1000
) t2
ON t.id = t2.id
WHERE t.status = 1
```

```html
$transactions = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(DB::raw("SELECT t.processing_time, t.paymentType, t.status, t.merchantTransactionId, t.paymentBrand, t.amount, t.currency, t.code, t.holder, t.bin, t.last4Digits, t.recurringType, m.name AS merchant, c.name AS channel, concat(UPPER(SUBSTRING(trim(sp.status_description),1,1)), lower(SUBSTRING(trim(sp.status_description),2))) as status_description
FROM transactionsV2 t
JOIN channels c
ON t.entityId = c.uuid
JOIN merchants m
ON m.uuid = c.sender
JOIN status_payments sp 
ON t.code = sp.status_code
JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.processing_time FROM transactionsV2 t
    JOIN channels c ON t.entityId = c.uuid
    JOIN merchants m ON m.uuid = c.sender
    WHERE (t.processing_time >= :insTs1)
    AND (t.processing_time <= :insTs2)
    AND (:merchant1 IS NULL OR m.name LIKE :merchant2)
    AND (:channel1 IS NULL OR c.name LIKE :channel2)
    ORDER BY t.processing_time DESC
    LIMIT 1000
) t2
ON t.id = t2.id
WHERE (:status1 IS NULL OR t.status = :status2)
AND (:holder1 IS NULL OR holder LIKE :holder2)
AND (:paymentType1 IS NULL OR t.paymentType IN (".$paymentType."))
AND (:merchantTransactionId1 IS NULL OR merchantTransactionId LIKE :merchantTransactionId2)
AND (:paymentBrand1 IS NULL OR paymentBrand LIKE :paymentBrand2)
AND (:amount1 IS NULL OR amount = :amount2)
AND (:recurringType1 IS NULL OR t.recurringType = :recurringType2)"),
['status1' => $search->searchCriteria['status'],
'status2' => $search->searchCriteria['status'],
'holder1' => $search->searchCriteria['holder'],
'holder2' => '%'.$search->searchCriteria['holder'].'%',
'paymentType1' => $paymentType,
'merchantTransactionId1' => $search->searchCriteria['merchantTransactionId'],
'merchantTransactionId2' => '%'.$search->searchCriteria['merchantTransactionId'].'%',
'paymentBrand1' => $search->searchCriteria['paymentBrand'],
'paymentBrand2' => '%'.$search->searchCriteria['paymentBrand'].'%',
'amount1' => $search->searchCriteria['amount'],
'amount2' => $search->searchCriteria['amount'],
'recurringType1' => $search->searchCriteria['recurringType'],
'recurringType2' => $search->searchCriteria['recurringType'],
'merchant1' => $search->searchCriteria['merchant'],
'merchant2' => '%'.$search->searchCriteria['merchant'].'%',
'channel1' => $search->searchCriteria['channel'],
'channel2' => '%'.$search->searchCriteria['channel'].'%',
'insTs1' => $search->searchCriteria['fromDate'] . ' 00:00:00',
'insTs2' => $search->searchCriteria['toDate'] . ' 23:59:59']);
```

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0 mate

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see that the subquery requires the `join`s.  Does this suffice?

```
SELECT t.id, t.processing_time
FROM transactionsV2 t
WHERE t.processing_time >= '2018-11-08' AND
      t.processing_time <= '2018-11-13'
ORDER BY t.processing_time DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

If so, an index on `transactionsV2(processing_time)` would help (assuming that it is not a view).

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned this earlier. This query is actually a shortened version of a much bigger query that contains more where clauses so it is required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the subquery is redundant since it is independent subquery and you are doing the join according to a primary key (`transactionsV2.id`). You can simply use

```
SELECT t.processing_time, 
       t.paymentType, 
       t.status, 
       t.merchantTransactionId, 
       t.paymentBrand, 
       t.amount, 
       t.currency, 
       t.code, 
       t.holder, 
       t.bin, 
       t.last4Digits, 
       t.recurringType, 
       m.name AS merchant, 
       c.name AS channel, 
       concat(UPPER(SUBSTRING(trim(sp.status_description),1,1)), 
       lower(SUBSTRING(trim(sp.status_description),2))) as status_description,
       row_number() over ()
FROM transactionsV2 t
JOIN channels c ON t.entityId = c.uuid
JOIN merchants m ON m.uuid = c.sender
WHERE (t.processing_time >= "2018-11-08 00:00:00") AND (t.processing_time <= "2018-11-12 23:59:59") and t.status = 1
ORDER BY t.processing_time DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned this earlier. This query is actually a shortened version of a much bigger query that contains more where clauses so it is required.